# UWP: Crop an image to a circle

Tags: image-processing, uwp

In UWP, how do I crop an image (stored as a byte[]) into a circle shape.
To be clear - I don't need this in the UI - I need to crop the actual image.
The process would more or less work as follows (I think):

- convert the byte[] into UWP image construct (`BitmapDecoder`?)
- crop image from the center into a square shape
- clip the bounds of the square image to make a circle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [free open-source library `ImageSharp`](https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp) which offers circular cropping functionality and even offers a working sample with exactly this. The library is compatible with .NET Standard 1.3 so it should work in your UWP app without any problem. The circular crop sample is [here on GitHub](https://github.com/SixLabors/Samples/tree/master/ImageSharp/AvatarWithRoundedCorner) as well.

The key part of the code is here:

```cs
// This method can be seen as an inline implementation of an `IImageProcessor`:
// (The combination of `IImageOperations.Apply()` + this could be replaced with an `IImageProcessor`)
public static void ApplyRoundedCorners(Image<Rgba32> img, float cornerRadius)
{
    IPathCollection corners = BuildCorners(img.Width, img.Height, cornerRadius);

    var graphicOptions = new GraphicsOptions(true) {
        AlphaCompositionMode = PixelAlphaCompositionMode.DestOut // enforces that any part of this shape that has color is punched out of the background
    };
    // mutating in here as we already have a cloned original
    // use any color (not Transparent), so the corners will be clipped
    img.Mutate(x => x.Fill(graphicOptions, Rgba32.LimeGreen, corners));
}

public static IPathCollection BuildCorners(int imageWidth, int imageHeight, float cornerRadius)
{
    // first create a square
    var rect = new RectangularPolygon(-0.5f, -0.5f, cornerRadius, cornerRadius);

    // then cut out of the square a circle so we are left with a corner
    IPath cornerTopLeft = rect.Clip(new EllipsePolygon(cornerRadius - 0.5f, cornerRadius - 0.5f, cornerRadius));

    // corner is now a corner shape positions top left
    //lets make 3 more positioned correctly, we can do that by translating the orgional artound the center of the image

    float rightPos = imageWidth - cornerTopLeft.Bounds.Width + 1;
    float bottomPos = imageHeight - cornerTopLeft.Bounds.Height + 1;

    // move it across the width of the image - the width of the shape
    IPath cornerTopRight = cornerTopLeft.RotateDegree(90).Translate(rightPos, 0);
    IPath cornerBottomLeft = cornerTopLeft.RotateDegree(-90).Translate(0, bottomPos);
    IPath cornerBottomRight = cornerTopLeft.RotateDegree(180).Translate(rightPos, bottomPos);

    return new PathCollection(cornerTopLeft, cornerBottomLeft, cornerTopRight, cornerBottomRight);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Martin! For those following - here's a link to the code that takes byte[] image as input, and spits out cropped circle image as byte[] https://github.com/InquisitorJax/Xamarin-Forms-Syncfusion-Pdf/blob/master/Xam.Sf.FormsPdf/Xam.Sf.FormsPdf.UWP/WindowsImageUtility.cs

Answer (score 2):

In addition to ImageSharp, The UWP community toolkit also supplies some sample code on addressing image cropping using rect or circle:
https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls/ImageCropper/ImageCropper.Helpers.cs